# Google javascript SDK for logout issues

Tags: javascript, google-api, sdk, logout

I am trying to use standard Google javascript SDK for  logout

```
function googleLogout() {
  var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
  auth2.signOut().then(function () {
    console.log('User signed out.');
  });   
}
```

It executes without any error and displays "User signed out" but does not logout user from gmail (or any google signed in in another tab )

Comment: I'd guess that `GoogleAuth` isn't defined ... should it be?

Answer (score 0):

you need loaded your library first , Make sure it is loaded

```
<script src="https://xxxx"></script>
<script>
      function googleLogout() {
            var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
            auth2.signOut().then(function () {
                console.log('User signed out.');
            });
        }
</script>
```

Comment: It executes without any error and displays "User signed out" but does not logout user from gmail (or any google signed in in another tab )